# Is it possible to change MongoDB document field value after specific time?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to ban users by setting the field `accountBan: True` within their profile document within the `users` collection. I want this field to flip to `accountBan: False` after 72 hours. Is there a provision for this in MongoDB?

P.S. I am aware that mongoDB allows to expire entire documents within a collection, but I am looking to "flip a switch" within a document after a certain time. Any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: One solution is to log the timestamp after the user gets banned and make a cron job to check if it the Current timestamp - logged timestamp > 72 hours .

Comment: I thought of that solution, but what is a cron job?

Comment: Its like a timer that runs a function every X amount of time. In your case, your function will check if timestamp - logged timestamp > 72 hours